# asp.net calendar default month view

Tags: asp.net, calendar

By default asp.net calendar control shows dates of current month. How is it possible to change programatically default month view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [VisibleDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.visibledate%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) Property like:

```
int yourdesiredmonth = 5;
Calendar1.VisibleDate = new DateTime(Calendar1.TodaysDate.Year,yourdesiredmonth,1);
```